# my code no longer compiles when using GCC MinGW

Tags: android, c++, gcc, mingw

I wrote a small program using Visual Studio 2015. It compiles and runs properly. I am now attempting to run the same program using the GCC MinGW compiler so that I can port it to Android.
However the compiler keeps complaining. Here are the issues it keeps throwing up:

```
     inline auto currentTime()
     {
         return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
     }
```

The compiler complains:

> error: `auto` return without trailing return type; deduced return
>   types are a C++14 extension.

The compiler also complains about this line

```
      return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

> error: no viable conversion from returned value of type `time_point`
>     (aka `time_point < std::__ndk1::chrono::steady_clock, duration < long, long ratio < 1LL, 1000000000LL > > >`) to function return type `int`

Is there any way I can get around these problems without having to rewrite that part of my code?

Comment: Did you turn on C++14?

Comment: I'm using APP_STL := c++_static in application.mk to include my cplusplus standard library

Comment: I'm not sure the bundled GCC from the Android NDK supports C++14 (yet), take a look at [CrystaX NDK](https://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk), it's a fork of the Android NDK with C++14 support

Comment: CrystaX NDK is not tested bor supported for windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Android.mk APP_STL := c++_shared. This means that the NDK is set to use the LLVM C++ runtime shared library. This runtime is an Anroid port of LLVM libc++. By default this runtime compiles with -std=c++11. I set this-> LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++14. After that the code referenced above compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out the type of ::now();
Then replace auto with that type you found,

```
inline int currentTime()
{
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
```

like this ^^

Comment: Author explicitly said *get around these problems **without** having to rewrite that part of my code*..

Comment: so I changed auto to int and that mistake has been solved, but the second one persists

Comment: if you're still having issues, the problem is that `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` does *not* return `int` (don't know why the answer states that), but rather `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`, that is what `auto` actually stands for in your code, so that should be the return type if you can't use `auto`.